# CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess) -- not passing verbose along

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

For some reason, even thought I've set CmdletBinding(SupportShouldProcess), I'm not getting output from write-verbose. I've snipped the actual execution stuff, but it doesn't produce any verbose output when run with -verbose -whatif.  I thought I understood this and I have another script that works correctly this way.

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

$CLUSTERS = @("hyper-v-failovercluster")
$DAYS=-8 
$NODES = @();
foreach ($CLUSTER in $CLUSTERS) {
    $NODES+=(Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $CLUSTER)
    }

$CHECKPOINTS= Get-VMSnapshot –ComputerName $NODES -VMName * | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt ( ( Get-Date).AddDays($DAYS)) } 

$PSCmdlet | Select-Object * 

foreach ( $CHECKPOINT in $CHECKPOINTS) {
    if ($CHECKPOINT.Name -match '^SNAP_HOLD\:') { 
        Write-Verbose "Skipping and renaming $CHECKPOINT.Name"
        $NEW_NAME = $CHECKPOINT.Name -replace '^SNAP_HOLD\:',''
  # do stuff here
        } else {
  # do stuff here
        }
}
```

Comment: What "verbose" output are you expecting to see? `SupportsShouldProcess` doesn't "enable" the use of `-Verbose`; with that said, you should still see your `Write-Verbose` message given that the condition is matched. It does make `-WhatIf` available however.

Comment: Add an empty `param()` block immediately after `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` (even if you don't declare any parameters)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, good catch! I completely missed that.

Comment: Mathias -- that did it.  If you send that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  Thank you.